# BCP entire record to one field in sql server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

I am using bulkcopy to insert (large) text files into SQL server. Until now I always used a table like this

create table mijndatabase.dbo.invoer 
(
veld varchar(max)
)
Then I use the following DOS batch file

bcp mijndatabase.dbo.invoer in C:\pad\bestand.txt -c -T -S AC01\ST01

Or in C#

```
            string command = @"bcp mijndatabase.dbo.invoer in C:\pad\bestand.txt -c -T -S AC01\ST01"

            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (Process proc = new Process())
            {
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();

            }
```

What should I do when I want to bulkcopy the file to a field in a multi field table without splitting the input file so say I have a table

create table mijndatabase.dbo.invoer2 
(
nr int identity(1,1),
veld1 varchar(max),
veld2 varchar(1000),
veld3 varchar(1000)
)

and the input file should be bulk-copied to veld1, the other fields should not be used.

What to do, is / are there extra parameters to use?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Regards,

John

Comment: This is *NOT* SqlBulkCopy, it's BCP.  They are completely different things (one is a client API call, the other is a server command-line utility) that happen to serve very similar purposes in very different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a format file to skip the unwanted fields.  Below is a link to MSDN for the BCP command.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Make sure the fields have default values.  The identity is fine by itself, just define for all other fields.

Here are some articles I did on BCP / BULK INSERT.

http://craftydba.com/?tag=export

If you still have questions, just holler.

I will need some sample data and the exact table definition (TSQL) to give you more exact details.

**[ -- Email from the user with more information --]**

I use the following table to import the data to

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_000_invoerbcp_01]
(
    [volgnr_01] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [veld_1_01] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [veld_2_01] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [veld_3_01] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [veld_4_01] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [veld_5_01] [varchar](1000) NULL
)
```

Crafty DBA modified the following format file given by the user.

```
10.0
6
1       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\t"     0     volgnr_01          ""
2       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\t"     2     veld_1_01          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\t"     0     veld_2_01          ""
4       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\t"     0     veld_3_01          ""
5       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\t"     0     veld_4_01          ""
6       SQLCHAR         0       0       "\r\n"   0     veld_5_01          ""
```

A definition of varchar(MAX) is the same as a 0 in length.  See msdn article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177478.aspx

To skip a field, make the data length and column orders blank.  See msdn article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx

Again, defining defaults is necessary if you do not want NULL values.

I hope this modified format file works for you.

Comment: I do not understand the comment you posted.  The -f allows you to use a format file.  That is key to you skipping fields.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: Sorry, this entry was a mistake